# How to deal with Selenium Sendkey UTF-8 Error

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium

1. My python environment are able to print UTF-8 characters.
2. Add " u " in front of UTF-8 characters CAN PASS selenium argument but it turns
   wrong UTF -8 characters in browser search result .

   ```
   from selenium import webdriver

   dr = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='C:/Python27/Lib/selenium/geckodriver.exe')
   dr.get('http://google.com/')

   search_bx = dr.find_element_by_name('q')
   search_bx.send_keys('ﾀｶｾﾌﾞｯｻﾝ　広島\n')
   ```

   - *Without "executable_path=" command , selenium don't even involve browser
   - *Don't know how to search(element name) directly in "Firefox" URL address bar, so i put dr.get('http://google.com/') script.

Comment: This is the error meassage : UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc0 in position 0: invalid start byte

Comment: You are on Python 2. You must use explicit Unicode strings: `u'ﾀｶｾﾌﾞｯｻﾝ　広島\n'` (note the `u`). Also double-check that the .py file is saved as UTF-8 and has a proper [coding hint](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) at the top: `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`

Comment: It is work . coding hint is the solution of my porblem  . Thank you Tomalak.